# replacing the beginning and end but not the same chars within a string

Tags: c#, regex, replace, contains

```
lines = "some stuff\"some other \"stuff\"\"";
lines = lines.Replace("\"", "\"");
lines = lines.Replace("\"", "\"");
```

in its current context and in its simplest form these two actions seem absolutely pointless but when I put this into code it will be not be pointless and will have a purpose other than replacing itself with itself.

OK so I have the String lines that has 4 escaped quotation marks and I wish to replace the first quote with a quote and the end quote with a quote how would I accomplish this without replacing any of the inner quotes?

Comment: You want to replace a quaote with a quote? can you please post what the result should look like :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IndexOf and LastIndexOf to find the first and last quotes. Then use Substring to replace the quotes:

```
lines = "some stuff\"some other \"stuff\"\"";
firstQuote = lines.IndexOf("\"");
lastQuote = lines.LastIndexOf("\"");
lines = lines.Substring(0, firstQuote) + "\"" + lines.Substring(firstQuote + 1, lastQuote) + "\"" + lines.Substring(lastQuote + 1, lines.Length);
```

Comment: just wondering should the lastquote in  lines.Substring(firstQuote + 1, lastQuote) + ">"; be lastqoute - 1? (the second lines.substring()) because this currently breaks due to length being out of bounds    http://ideone.com/CCxwMB

Comment: huh ignore my comment about the - 1 because endQuote is = 29 and lines = 30 but the param length is still out of bounds?

Comment: You're using Substr, but my example uses Substring. To make it work with Substr, you need to subtract the first parameter from the second. For example, lines.Substring(firstQuote + 1, lastQuote) becomes lines.Substr(firstQuote + 1, lastQuote - (firstQuote + 1))

Comment: I copied your example exactly and just changed all occurrences of "lines" to "input" where am i using Substr instead of Substring?

Comment: Apparently your language has the names reversed. Normally, Subtring has the params (start, end), whereas Substr has the params (start, length). So just subtract off the parameters as in my previous comment and it should work.